# Encryption and Decryption I want the method that he used to encrypt

Tags: c#, encryption

I have got a string for you guys.

Normal string = nmrufETK
Encrypted string = ultYIi4GtHhb//Cl0J8wIg==

Here is the things that I know so far, the old decyrption method was :

```
public static List<string> hadibuloc = new List<string>();

            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("OZt4nd8ZZpAEnZBdU3Z7");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("fkheb1PFtPIKTi05Zpzz");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("0kx96D8OzZ3rznUk4qyi");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("TgAji9cqMALlhJV12elB");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("0XQ3XXjUo3HTzzevUmDm");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("F3Ib4qRHXDgQwoJyhWra");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("eRWoJ0s1B0uln8fFgxqX");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("iUE0FKl2Ntawpt6sbV7u");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("me9fMa0WTreWRrmYpBh7");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("kyJB0qCUq269fzREzRxD");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("WnTufxOov40st4L6qZF9");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("7csfQq3YunqM9ziygmw8");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("EyqWVpgOvZkyJCAmlgCh");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("D2RAYhyatrMYrZjLdlqL");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("nSdcM6NAAyekiwYHQqZl");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("B3RPgAHYEpwKsFCkrLSq");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("JgQuRU88IQC5Z77JUTiD");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("v57wd6YIJTGhettATB8L");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Qzc1nrxQwuIOMrGynhXu");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("ad5AKkogV91AfmdNwkEO");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("vaG2jNiDHa5p18hazzyZ");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("BbYJbJOcX4w5F84nrWYl");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("QGMq1ffFpBV64UpWeLCP");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("lrLJqwoJGAuwmqA12MWR");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("VFqyK09HS3920srKbBvp");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("wVjVwspocrBWWAnFz53M");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("oGMgDdEBpy8vHa5RZQHa");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("BAUsGUgYBvi7tGMJRmy6");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("l1nEhAHzWbRlGQeOi9pz");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("PLpbqWSUnkAoLJam79cD");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("SWbChkYzbfB0XKKcE1wb");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("ZRlERlOLlbbW7l4u4SLB");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("4FaDBRIw2bRkeqLALQwq");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Z3Yb3QdFgAbOUMD4TT2E");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("0QjIrotDsTJrBMVOUGEx");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("rrBABwOTnnjoZH81Y10w");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Ig8OIDYp7SaHel8gQhYE");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Zkcq9DLCmmMb2pvgsnox");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Ta9QRpW1vH3vYNaWDuaT");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("I5B3gCvXSrgfg7aKdyJ8");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("F5U7PteCDqjtT2YYMbte");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("NOzV5qhSRxEmEwHGrjSv");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("9Ocg4R5TAqIQLJVY9aJA");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("AoXect0Wd914NAKW957w");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("ebNIGbCQ5e4vRkoKQ4SN");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("DyQb0qmcovqZS6xA5Nbq");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("7HjmPVonDspqmixH2FrJ");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("EqU8wj6HBrXi5nW9l16l");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("NI85VXOjCS0dgtylMyt1");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("zFjG4ZJbkzrZxPwW5C1P");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("sqkTwAiMc5iMRvam2AHs");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Kd2XiFoFdCheMCsD5SNk");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("2PcWLkcAiLOo4AcM1n6f");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("fZKaPRgxgb6EGc9A4epo");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("pJCNj8hiQYd0mSwAAlG9");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("FHLEOcgR8nZkPETgIau7");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("fP0IIV133SBrSAhcm2xL");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("J7dYgJsix1trFydJBCiD");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("kuy5ZNe3SKh6NNwKsusq");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("yw35qZxwIPY4vAndktx3");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("lFIn4TrpaXAL6TUXTfRa");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("2ajBkzl7mSl08rm0m9qq");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("rQiGJrCD2qOw2cbTrHdX");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("08Gm5pOBmKQPIpWw7NIu");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("WRjgeZMotIAmyiGalpt3");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("rYy1MGiBLxfMBufX9IJn");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("LIv4dk2eh1DbWmuP2Xao");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("xeNNc12ef0pmgBs3rYpV");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("6IcTB4F0MYf3XEvPZ3Pp");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("4FEEfd1l5qNsoX7VPkiS");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("0kGF2Rb8HKT4Spn41RW1");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("HDEsDvrgokF0b5jgXJ3J");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("iU1NeT7jYaN7HB8eNn9V");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("NT4HJ9M77hkWK3TqaFRR");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("GEFxqMf38desyg3wO1K4");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Zgwk37JrBl9o3JMeQtZA");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("64YkqXguAr8AmWTNKQj3");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("tGWLK6h9TPrSFSA4ZocS");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("9yHnDOfweXcCXOp1chBx");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("LTuAf0bPkFYrQ5TbMD6U");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("M4k0pUF7P04bLHs6dJV1");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("x5X0gVtjCe8GDrfOFsaX");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("BrFjmwvJMKjmLg5mYWRQ");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("4iAcBuNr58pP2gux67ud");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("jLuuVi2la7KfxRNNecG5");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("3QssdnIkbDrMcQWQ2lsb");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("7wvkS2KuPwCOApEMJW2s");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("1ZxJdP8JxP4PR1t4yE9D");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("aFL5rH066RA3eLF6BSrm");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("pAvKpwz4fc4lmtsbNjHO");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("ukOhB5O7NxLMgyC0q1rb");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("69qB4rzAA4BsCYfY3c74");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("fKYNy6gkdPDyk0pTkkN2");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("l0SPSH2CeMdpPAa6tVP8");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("NQkNZKgSFEq8sDHUCLAf");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("yzM5F818BdeRcC8pHNjB");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("tj8hZFSq4blLgTdPMlv1");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("wXP72vnkO9eLMslKSphJ");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("hdtln0yAp9O2StGrXkZL");
            Functions.hadibuloc.Add("Ujvws8KLRf7fyz1oo9Fm");
```

```
        public static string Uzaksunucudangelenmetnicoz(string metin)
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                List<string> list = new List<string>();
                list.Add("6MRVk2iHrsSWxY739uU6");
                list.Add("JNEbV73AIVv01UI4cCN9");
                list.Add("fRUzPptifIk7mYhAGuwq");
                list.Add("4okJUC1Nv8hT2RjIOlDH");
                list.Add("jWJjtopKxt27xbPUmigk");
                list.Add("cQiqthahKNnbJXUsXNai");
                list.Add("LrGUCKUxIKsbHEoGNoZB");
                list.Add("j3UVDV6B5P3ZTewgLs1J");
                list.Add("a864WixaWMit6RdbnowV");
                list.Add("bLfWxqaXSEsa9uNoDY1z");
                list.Add("aTwGuGAL1aDEYLqZdydm");
                list.Add("fipquWXp6Fde1l1yoePJ");
                list.Add("xEFesiTXtE8GNiJoPURP");
                list.Add("z1rleac3uxRnrwrlZ47P");
                list.Add("HnauZy36NMCbnKQpBvXy");
                list.Add("LsenKihueSeUm5D3vyGm");
                list.Add("fBAvk2yApQGD90wPmTuz");
                list.Add("kL61T5rai5sq1fPDPQIG");
                list.Add("u4lTisX4LxhTouLGiVqv");
                list.Add("dhgB32wDm0PgUccGC7vi");
                list.Add("pDMQv1GbeU2h3aOP2aFf");
                list.Add("Z9tMsKaXoC9569dQWLoH");
                list.Add("wwl9YoScNaklEk6lYBRk");
                list.Add("61oIv3D0asY8qHcsMvvn");
                list.Add("AcUgy8GNAKmUmsi1wJZ2");
                list.Add("cxAIFZaLeEYooksNACUm");
                list.Add("hXtoz3WI4WWcD15U1HVj");
                list.Add("1xU1M828PODASWox3CWc");
                list.Add("XGJ6H04SndlopxeuJR2X");
                list.Add("7XsDr8tAklPAUhRwgS31");
                list.Add("SyUH2DS12ObKTXYzapMm");
                list.Add("eyRb3S2EOIfnfHJZImOr");
                list.Add("x47P7emhboAYBbSGN9BP");
                list.Add("u2hp1Lnq0dJWqh5CXwFx");
                list.Add("2DwFQJGsQdd46liK6YfI");
                list.Add("qzlgXi9wFVsevBVljM7P");
                list.Add("7iaN5LVfWpes5IZtvNJs");
                list.Add("BjTUTmlDb9Haj3iiL4H8");
                list.Add("E0vZK3rAmSD5TJQYqo06");
                list.Add("cV0nXoWnC2qfAF6ijKti");
                list.Add("ZnXX4xjkWxyhVzAE5f4T");
                list.Add("uiBq4ynA6zVpvYcLG3Rr");
                list.Add("iQddCas3XU4Wg1kJd0VG");
                list.Add("TbLVNp3vf1d3uVYpNA9V");
                list.Add("S9VKQiW7fMONpIZLoiZp");
                list.Add("782urFNgLyB4NsVMF5PL");
                list.Add("d0FetEyv8Kcpb4xsq4WL");
                list.Add("vDxNe5VujuZxfmVWFzDO");
                list.Add("eqSfybAFoNRwaWjTwGKl");
                list.Add("pme5Rz3bm3afIJUNvGao");
                list.Add("5GYm7wSxmD2XTfa1fMW2");
                list.Add("G4pMJhDsO95pIAL8cPmS");
                list.Add("htdFa3r1vnR3YfHoj518");
                list.Add("AVwD2PBtkLy2IC6WPG3x");
                list.Add("PCbXpVgmU0psYRcRLhDj");
                list.Add("aoHChiGFaFSa4fy5lVcY");
                list.Add("nDGKEbbKdNn1qF7YziCT");
                list.Add("g9Caz2rzK3BrZM9Yywnk");
                list.Add("9MDd0QU1Wasw7PARMzfC");
                list.Add("BDTGEK8nSErokxtpx5qI");
                list.Add("kAoxMqmbts92s2SvjXCQ");
                list.Add("tI2AMshUkr7NvwjWWMWK");
                list.Add("wjwPea52QEF5XteTWTBR");
                list.Add("6QcQXhY6YhfaBOof38X9");
                list.Add("T3ztIItPddcqCa6l4W9q");
                list.Add("fk61VH7gogvZqScilAjc");
                list.Add("rNiGeeaesugz1EuIhlkA");
                list.Add("MUo3726lbUu1noFFdNQL");
                list.Add("hXh5Ojy9M2mhscBQIFsU");
                list.Add("UOC2A4ql6K0FnExnuy5N");
                list.Add("jgQBAXfvMZ4anhRJkrhw");
                list.Add("BCaFEzbVQZDSDePt2aOK");
                list.Add("WwK7FAI1M3P6iLHChuDe");
                list.Add("UyQTMeFsYPFWPmwSsyAn");
                list.Add("LCJI9dPxYZUIpbVOLRXa");
                list.Add("AljvoFtljUvbetI2uAm8");
                list.Add("J9dS4PNwjQY95ZJrWgZK");
                list.Add("LNXcRGdEUfZoaFUxYvnz");
                list.Add("9TGNyTWYec9O5j77yKH2");
                list.Add("0VfAzTM1kSPW1AEPgUgy");
                list.Add("oPPBTadoRQuryClE6Set");
                list.Add("LK5Taw6rC5LIqD8XlMuw");
                list.Add("zydeLNO5dDco6rcniPQo");
                list.Add("qorqKozLU6AEK00sij17");
                list.Add("em5FrXNJf7dlUrPmMZAb");
                list.Add("XGhnM6PUAbF6rqnumKN6");
                list.Add("xobFyWikgplryg4zJ71Y");
                list.Add("r7xh75Hg3Q1tjzx01zlb");
                list.Add("3cUXFakPJAzY8TlO1g6t");
                list.Add("ZaM8ELOP57j8wvagTkgj");
                list.Add("YZtR13683gxaYnfHt2m2");
                list.Add("uXjIph0fYIQUApaDhswh");
                list.Add("yDewQ1dWb39AKRszMl2x");
                list.Add("8wf1DTnyLhDICzoppHex");
                list.Add("ubO0rGOZpD4WMN1zZYMS");
                list.Add("iXS26dUzA4NFOAwHgHyg");
                list.Add("XOHZ5TOPuMF8YqqWRXb8");
                list.Add("oJzOJ5zoZKA6wnHJcJNZ");
                list.Add("rzWXMzAgaWwZ2POulBbU");
                list.Add("g7LoA9c7fNTnBbTWPBPu");
                list.Add("uVCH6x1GfXEkB561Lx61");
                list.Add("BJruYhyvqBtXTvZk93ua");
                list.Add("uCkfQp4gFBOzlZTM59kn");
                list.Add("yZD9B59o92Eqmbe3mJG5");
                list.Add("vgdoztnujq9BTPoiQaQP");
                list.Add("jfyJazaJJ3HgyUCmbVhN");
                list.Add("MoZTMDMVMg3pFE94Q0Hp");
                list.Add("sSHRIeqtDRWRIl3hqA50"); 
                list.Add("4Bz3N3tfDwkyckMoJjVO");
                list.Add("hBS3Dk5CN2VpWRmtbaxa");
                SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create();
                byte[] key = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(list[6].Substring(6)));
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                sha.Dispose();
                result = Functions.DecryptString(metin, key, iv);
            }
            catch
            {
                result = "undefined";
            }
            return result;
        }
    public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] array = new byte[32];
            Array.Copy(key, 0, array, 0, 32);
            aes.Key = array;
            aes.IV = iv;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateDecryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                byte[] array2 = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                cryptoStream.Write(array2, 0, array2.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] array3 = memoryStream.ToArray();
                result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array3, 0, array3.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

And this was the old encrytion method :

```
        public static string AES256Hash(string plaintext)
        {
            SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create();
            byte[] key = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Functions.hadibuloc[87].Substring(8)));
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            sha.Dispose();
            return Functions.EncryptString(plaintext, key, iv);
        }
public static string EncryptString(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            Aes aes = Aes.Create();
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            byte[] array = new byte[32];
            Array.Copy(key, 0, array, 0, 32);
            aes.Key = array;
            aes.IV = iv;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ICryptoTransform transform = aes.CreateEncryptor();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
            cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] array2 = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(array2, 0, array2.Length);
        }
```

But as I said these were old codes that used. And I think he used a method that similar to these. I want the method that he used to encrypt. My english is not good if theres and spelling or grammer mistake sorry for that if you didnt understand my question you feel free to ask again.

Answer (score 0):

It will be impossible to determine an encryption algorithm without source code or some amount of reverse engineering. The old encryption uses AES256 in CBC mode, but that is obvious.

If you don't have access to the new code, then you probably shouldn't be attempting this anyways..

Comment: Ok , I'll change my question the decryptstring method is not working it says padding is invalid I tried all the padding mode and yet it didn't work